# Jetpack Compose Accompanist Navigation Animation in Reuse composable

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am using the navigation animation in [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist)

There are the following ways to use

```
AnimatedNavHost(navController, startDestination, Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {

        composable("greet",
            enterTransition = { // push
                slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(400))
            },
            popExitTransition = { // pop
                slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(300))
            },

            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(400))
            },
            popEnterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(350))
            }

        ) { GreetView(navController) }

}
```

Since the definitions are all the same in `composable`, how can I reuse `composable`.

Simplified as follows:

```
AnimatedNavHost() {

        composable("greet") {
                // ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an extension function with receiver `NavGraphBuilder` where you pre-populate all your transitions and just add the sections which will change.

Here is an example based on your question.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.composable(
    route: String,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    val enterTransition =
        slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(400))

    val exitTransition =
        slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(400))

    val popExitTransition =
        slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(300))

    val popEnterTransition =
        slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(350))

    composable(
        route = route,
        enterTransition = { _, _ ->
            enterTransition
        },
        popEnterTransition = { _, _ ->
            popEnterTransition
        },
        popExitTransition = { _, _ ->
            popExitTransition
        },
        exitTransition = { _, _ ->
            exitTransition
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Now you can just go ahead and use it from your navigation graph as,

```
composable("greet"){

}
```

When you type `composable` from your navigation graph, Android Studio may try and use the default one so you should make sure you are using your extension function instead. To simplify it, you can rename the extension function from `composable` to something else.

Comment: Yes, I also used the extension, but it didn't work. Your way is more simplified, but can't find `slideOutOfContainer`, how to import it?

Comment: I also don't know where `slideOutOfContainer` comes from. I copied it from your own question  @gaohomway

Comment: I solved it like this, thanks a lot
`val enterTransition: AnimatedContentScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition? = {
        slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(400))
    }`

Comment: I usually just use slides in screen transitions. You can replace with 
`slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { -1000 }, animationSpec = tween(350))`

Comment: @gaohomway thanks for following up on the issue on GitHub. `AnimatedContentTransitionScope<*>` changed to `AnimatedContentTransitionScope` in the [Compose Animation 1.5.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.5.0-alpha01) release.